# Spray marshalling collection of ToResponseMarshallable

Tags: scala, collections, response, marshalling, spray

I have a simple Spray scenario that doesn't work as I've expected.

I have a spray server that dispatches work to different modules, and then return their composed responses.

As I don't want to limit Module responses, I chose that the Module's method return ToResponseMarshallable, as I have Modules that need to return a plain String.

Module signature could be:

**def moduleProcessing(): ToResponseMarshallable = randomString()**

And my "complete" block look similar to this:

```
complete {   

    val response1 = moduleProcessing()
    val response2 = moduleProcessing()
    Seq(response1,response2) 
}
```

In the previous example, I would expect to get:

[{"someRandomString"},{"anotherRandomString"}]

But I am getting:

[{},{}]

Of course it will propagate as expected, if I return a single response or if I change the signature of the moduleProcessing return type to any Marshallable Type.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's strange that your `moduleProcessing` method returns directly a `ToResponseMarshallable[T]`. The *spray way* would be to have this method return a `T` and have an in scope `Marshaller[T]` for when you complete requests by providing a `T`.

Finally, I don't think `Marshaller.of[Seq[T]]` is a [built in marshaller in spray](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-httpx/marshalling/#custom-marshallers).

This means you'll need to provide your own `Seq` marshaller. This could delegate the actual marshalling of each item in the seq to an implicit `Marshaller[T]` and concatenate the results. [Many builtin spray marshallers](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/269ce885d3412e555237bb328aae89457f57c660/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/marshalling/MetaMarshallers.scala#L27) require implicit `Marshaller[T]` values like this. Alternatively, if you want a simple `Seq[T]` to string marshaller, try something like the following:

```
implicit val CustomMarshaller = Marshaller.delegate[Seq[T], String](`text/html`)(_.mkString("{", ",", "}"))
```